# Firebase: Access the database from URL

Tags: ios, swift, http, firebase-realtime-database, vungle-ads

In my Swift app, I am going to be using Vungle for incentivized ads. The way this works is that the Vungle Servers will ping any URL that I give them. For example:

> myapp.firebase.com/db_location/section/user_id/?value=123

I have looked around lots of websites and now my head hurts as I cannot seem to find a solution. Is there a way to insert into my Firebase database (securely, without write all access) request that is sent via a URL?

This would be similar I assume to the API Gateway that AWS supplies.

Looking for advice, pointers/tutorials etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) which allows you to insert into your database using POST requests.

An example using curl from the documentation:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"user_id" : "jack", "text" : "Ahoy!"}' \
  'https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/message_list.json'
```